# OpenGL using fragment shader to go from RGBA to ARGB

Tags: android, opengl-es

A simple issue, I want to convert RGBA to ARGB. Instead of manually adjusting the bytes in a for-loop after getting them from OpenGL `glReadPixels`, I was thinking I'd just use a simple fragment shader to output the pixel byte order as ARGB instead of the standard RGBA.

Very simply:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 outColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    gl_FragColor = outColor.argb;
}
```

Then I grab them like so:

```
Gdx.gl.glPixelStorei(GL20.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
byteBufferPixels.clear();
Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, fbo.getWidth(), fbo.getHeight(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBufferPixels);

byteBufferPixels.clear();
byteBufferPixels.get(bytesARGB);
```

I figured it doesn't matter that in the fragment shader I put "A" in the "R" channel and "R" in the "B" channel, etc..., since I'm not actually rendering anything - I simply want the raw byte data in this order. But apparently it does matter, because it doesn't give correct results? I thought they were all just 0-1 channels? Is there any way I can trick OpenGL into getting this to work?

Note I can't change `GL_RGBA` in glReadPixels as that does not play nice with iOS.

---

**Edit, input and output:**

**Input**

[image]

**gl_FragColor = outColor.argb;**

[image]

**gl_FragColor = outColor.bgra;**

[image]

It's not actually respecting the channels at all?

If I do not apply the shader, and shuffle RGBA to ARGB via CPU for-loop, it works fine.

Comment: What results do you get for what input? Can you give some examples? You might be getting wrong values because of gamma correction, make sure all textures (input and framebuffer) are set to linear. Also, `gl_FragColor = vec4(outColor.a, outColor.r, outColor.g, outColor.b);` Can be written as `gl_FragColor = outColor.argb;`.

Comment: @tkausl input and output added to the question, i don't quite get how the blue channel remains accurate but everything else doesnt - not sure about the gamma you mentioned, input is from an RGBA8888 FBO which is rendered with the shader above to another RGBA8888 FBO, both set texture filters to linear as well. Also, if I DO NOT apply the shader, and simply shuffle the RGBA to ARGB in a for-loop in CPU (from output texture btw), it does work

Comment: Make sure you're using `GL_ONE, GL_ZERO` for your blendFunc you use to draw this to the frame buffer, or turn off gl blending.

Comment: @Tenfour04 sometimes the image will have transparency tho, its user-generated content

Comment: Yes, and that’s the blend func you need to put it in the frame buffer and be able to retrieve the alpha in the frame buffer. It fully replaces the alpha of each pixel in the frame buffer instead of allowing it to get multiplied by the pixel alpha that’s already in the destination. Pre-multiply your alpha in the shader if you need to also display this framebuffer’s texture on screen.

Comment: @Tenfour04 love you dude, that worked, sorcery